# How to find aria-label element using contains in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get information that is within the anchor tag but not the `href`. I want to extract the rating score from a few sellers on eBay. In the following HTML-Code, you can see where the rating score can be found. Is there a way to get the information about the "Bewertungspunktestand" (German for rating score) without using the `href`, because the `href` changes from the seller to seller? The rating score in this example would be 32. Since the text "Bewertungspunktestand" is only in this line, I thought it would be possible to let it search for this text and extract the aria-label with this text in it.

This is the link to [this example](https://www.ebay.de/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Laptop-mit-Touchbar-512GB-MPTT2D-A-Wie-neu/133585540546?nordt=true&nma=true&orig_cvip=true).

This is the Python code I tried and didn't work out:

```
try: 
    trans = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Bewertungspunktestand']")
except:
    trans = '0'
```

And this is the HTML-Code

```
<span class="mbg-l">
    (<a href="http://feedback.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback&amp;userid=thuanhtran&amp;iid=133585540546&amp;ssPageName=VIP:feedback&amp;ftab=FeedbackAsSeller&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trksid=p2047675.l2560" aria-label="Bewertungspunktestand: 32">32</a>
    <span class="vi-mbgds3-bkImg  vi-mbgds3-fb10-49" aria-label="Gelber Stern für 10 bis 49 Bewertungspunkte" role="img"></span>)
</span>
```

Comment: Perhaps `trans = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Bewertungspunktestand')]")`?

Answer (score 15):

Sure you can. Use XPATH's contains method, combined with the abiltiy to select any attribute (@aria-label):

```
//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Bewertungspunktestand:')]
```

Specifically to get the text value of that link element:

```
trans = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@aria-label, 'Bewertungspunktestand:')]").text
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of *aria-label* attribute isn't `Bewertungspunktestand` but `Bewertungspunktestand: 32`.

To print the value i.e. `32` from the `innerHTML` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.de/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Laptop-mit-Touchbar-512GB-MPTT2D-A-Wie-neu/133585540546?nordt=true&nma=true&orig_cvip=true')
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[aria-label^='Bewertungspunktestand']").text)
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.de/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Laptop-mit-Touchbar-512GB-MPTT2D-A-Wie-neu/133585540546?nordt=true&nma=true&orig_cvip=true')     
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Bewertungspunktestand')]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.de/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Laptop-mit-Touchbar-512GB-MPTT2D-A-Wie-neu/133585540546?nordt=true&nma=true&orig_cvip=true')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-label^='Bewertungspunktestand']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ebay.de/itm/Apple-MacBook-Pro-15-Laptop-mit-Touchbar-512GB-MPTT2D-A-Wie-neu/133585540546?nordt=true&nma=true&orig_cvip=true')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Bewertungspunktestand')]"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  MyMercy User
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)